# Imported Products Not In Catalog --> Manage Products

Tags: magento-1.9, import, catalog

I have imported about 150 products.  None of them show up in the backend under "Catalog --> Manage Products"  However I can see the products related to the categories under "Catalog --> Manage Categories".

Does anyone have any ideas why this may be happening?

[image]

Comment: Have you did reindexing after product upload ?

Comment: Yes... Everything is re-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Check in database tax_class_id, Status, qty is set for products or not.

If not please assign it.

After that refresh the cache and reindex all.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue when i import product. i solve this by doing below step.

1. create one product manualy
2. get the product id of newly create product
3. load product below id means if newly create product id is 96 than you load product using id 95 and get its data set status and visibility for that product and save that product.

now you check that product will available in catalog->product section

```
 <?php     
         $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(96);
         $product->setStatus(1);
         $product->setVisibility(4);
         $product->save();
    ?>
```